# Wifi issue on nexus 4 16GB

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

i had installed ubuntu on nexus 4 8GB and it ran ok, then i decided try into my nexus 4 16GB. In my nexus 4 16GB wifi doesn´t work, but i see imei code. Whats the problem.

I have tried some versions (quantal, raring, saucy,...) and the problem is the same.

Comment: What builds (eg date)?

Answer (score 2):

The radio from Android 4.4 KITKAT don't work with Ubuntu touch. Easily, I flashed radio with file from Android 4.3 and solved.

```
fastboot flash radio file.img
```

(`file.img` is the radio file from android 4.3)

Comment: What source from we can get this radio package of 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

get `radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1700.84.img`  from:
http://web.djodjo.org/article/download/android/ROM_images/factory_images_gn_occam

```
fastboot flash radio radio-mako-m9615a-cefwmazm-2.0.1700.84.img

fastboot reboot
```