# Wifi issue with after ubuntu install on nexus 4

Tags: wireless, nexus-4

cant connect phone with wifi. Nexus 4 was updated to kitkat before ubuntu install read that this must be the problem with kitkats radio. How to flash android jelly bean radio as not to have wifi problem. Thank you for your help.

This is my first question apologies for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a common issue when doing multiboot, check this website : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2538219

Also your question has been answered here : https://askubuntu.com/a/380779/226084